# Drawing a polygpn in JavaFx

Tags: canvas, javafx, polygon, fxml

Im new to javafx so please don't be harsh on me :)

Im trying to draw a polygon on a canvas using predefined set of points but i can't seem to understand how to go about doing it. 
Ive looked around for tutorials but they didn't seem to help.

Any help will be highly appreciated

EDIT:

FXML Code

```
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
   <children>
      <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.8995983935742972" layoutX="220.0" layoutY="99.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
               <children>
                  <Canvas height="444.0" layoutX="6.0" width="588.0" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Javafx Code

```
 @FXML
private Canvas canvas;

GraphicsContext gc;

public void drawShape(List<Point> points){
gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
gc.strokeRect(30, 100, 40, 40);
}
```

this returns a NullPointerException when i run it.

My problem is that i would like to draw the the shape defined on the canvas in theFXML document.

Comment: Do you have to use a canvas? There is a built-in [`Polygon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Polygon.html) class that you can just instantiate and add to a `Pane`. If you want to use a canvas, the `GraphicsContext` class has a [`strokePolygon(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#strokePolygon-double:A-double:A-int-) method.

Comment: I chose to use canvas because it seems easier to use. However, I'm using scene builder to create the gui. But I've failed to link the canvas created in scene to the controller. i get nullPointerException when i call gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D(); Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I've  edit the question and I've added the controller code. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set an `fx:id` on the `Canvas` in your fxml file. You need

```
<Canvas fx:id="canvas" height="444.0" layoutX="6.0" width="588.0" />
```

The value of the `fx:id` attribute must match the variable name in the controller.

You didn't show the context in which you call the `drawShape()` method; you need to be sure to call it after the `FXMLLoader` has injected the canvas defined in the fxml file into the controller. You can do this by calling `drawShape()` from the `initialize()` method, or from an event handler (but not from the constructor).